# ubuntu 16.04 do-relrase-update error

Tags: python3, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to update my ubuntu 16.04 server using 'do-release-update` and get an error:

```
# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,251 kB]
Fetched 1,252 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'
    
Checking package manager
    
Can not upgrade
    
Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3'
symlink.
```

But in my opinion, the link to python3 is configured correctly.

```
# python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jan 26 2021, 13:30:48)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

# update-alternatives --display python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3

# ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Oct 30 20:53 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.5
```

what could be wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is unfortunately out-of-support. You cannot upgrade. You have to do a clean install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 shipped with Python 3.5.1 and never upgraded from that, so that's what the upgrader is checking for.

Your output says that you have Python 3.5.2 installed.

If you cannot change the symlink back to 3.5.1 (perhaps those files have been removed), then the safest, fastest, and supported method is to backup your data and reinstall.

We generally recommend against changing or upgrading the version of python that comes with your release of Ubuntu. Doing so causes problems. If you want to use a different release of Python, you can install from source (instead of a deb) to prevent conflicts, or you can use a VM, container, or venv to keep the versions separate.

Comment: AFAIK, even if `python` is fixed, the OP will not be able to update or upgrade their system.